# Simplifying Python If Statements

Tags: python, if-statement, terminal, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner with python, and I am creating a two player tic tac toe game in terminal.  In total, this code takes up 139 lines, (this below being the relevant part of code I am having trouble with), however, this CheckWin function takes up around 40 lines of code, which I think is quite a lot compared to the amount of lines in this code, and considering that it performs a somewhat basic function.  Basically, in the game, this function checks whether a row, column, or diagonal, has three X's or three O's, and if it does, it assigns X to the winner and O to the winner.  Anyway, here is the code.

```
X = "X"
O = "O"
empty = " " 
S = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

def CheckWin(S):
    global winner
    winner = ""
    if S[0] == S[1] == S[2] != empty:
        if S[0] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[0] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[3] == S[4] == S[5] != empty:
        if S[3] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[3] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[6] == S[7] == S[8] != empty:
        if S[6] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[6] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[0] == S[3] == S[6] != empty:
        if S[0] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[0] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[1] == S[4] == S[7] != empty:
        if S[1] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[1] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[2] == S[5] == S[8] != empty:
        if S[2] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[2] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[0] == S[4] == S[8] != empty:
        if S[0] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[0] == O:
            winner = O
    if S[2] == S[4] == S[6] != empty:
        if S[2] == X:
            winner = X
        if S[2] == O:
            winner = O
```

Basically, I need help making the function much much simpler.  However, I do not want to eliminate the X, O, and winner variables, nor do I want to eliminate the list index method with the list S.  Even though, is there a way to simplify all these If statements, keeping these things?  If so, how?

Comment: For starters, you can get rid of loads by shortening all of the ``if S[n] == X: winner = X / if S[x] == O: winner = O`` to just ``winner = S[n]``. That'll save you 24 lines of code. :)

Comment: Consider using `for` loops and `range`.

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where the focus is about making existing running code better.

Comment: I assume the game stops when there is a winner?  You can probably write a `testRow` and `testCol` function for whatever row/column has the last input.  Then just do a test diagonals if that entry is on a diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks for "trios" of positions; you might as well have an object that holds this info:

```
trios = ((0,1,2), (3,4,5), (6,7,8), (0,3,6), (1,4,7), (2,5,8), (0,4,8), (2,4,6))
```

Then CheckWin would just loop through every trio, do that check you're doing, and return a winner if the trio matches. This way, CheckWin would be less than 10 lines of code.

I don't want to give it all away because I'm sure you can do it :)

Also, you don't need a global variable called "winner" inside CheckWin; just have CheckWin return the winner (or ""), and store the result in a variable outside the function itself.
I.e.

```
winner = CheckWin(S)
```

Comment: wow thanks, this is much easier, however, how do i make the trios variable work with the list S and it's indexes.

Comment: Something like, `for trio in trios` `if S[trio[0]] == S[trio[1]] == S[trio[2]]...`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a loop instead?

```
X, O = 'X', 'O'
S    = [X,O,X,O,X,O,O,X,O] # Test values
def CheckWin(S):
    index      = 0
    has_winner = False
    while index < len(S):
        print index
        if index <= 6: # after this point you won't find a winner (or you run this after every turn?)
            if (index % 3 == 0 and S[index] == S[index + 1] and S[index] == S[index + 2]): # horizontals
                has_winner = True
            elif index < 3: # verticals and diagonals (you only need the first row to know this)
                if (S[index] == S[(index + 3)] and S[index] == S[index + 6]) or \
                   (index == 0 and S[index] == S[4] and S[index] == S[8]) or \
                   (index == 2 and S[index] == S[4] and S[index] == S[6]):
                    has_winner = True
        if has_winner: # I'm using this to prevent duplicating code above (one if less)
            if S[index] in [X,O]:
                return S[index]
        index += 1
    return has_winner # If we have a winner but the X or O criterion isn't met, it returns False
winner = CheckWin(S)
```